# Restlet - Passing error status code and exception trace from server to client

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

We have a **restlet** server and client. We need to pass the error status and exception traces back to the client so that the client can take appropriate actions depending on the error status code. I read about `StatusService` and using `response.setStatus()` method but I can't get the specific exceptions thrown during server side processing be displayed on client side. The **DAO** layer from the server throws specific DB related exceptions and status code such as (Unique key violation etc), which the client needs to see and take appropriate actions.

Also, what is the common way of doing this to have centralized error *handling / processing* on server and client side ? Filters ?

A brief example will really help.

Thanks,
Deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send HTTP status codes and optionally your own description message. You can also send a representation of the error by overriding the getRepresentation in the StatusService.

```
@Override
public Status getStatus(Throwable throwable, Resource resource) {
    Status ret = null;
    Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
    if (cause == null) {
        Status status = super.getStatus(throwable, resource);
        ret = new Status(status, throwable.getMessage());
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected resource exception <" + ret.toString() + "> for throwable of type <" + throwable + "> at resource <" + resource + ">");
    } else if (cause instanceof NotFoundException) {
        ret = new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, cause, resource.getReference().toString());
        log.info("Not found <" + ret.toString() + "> for throwable of type <" + cause + "> at resource <" + resource + ">");
    } else if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationsException) {
        ConstraintViolationsException e = (ConstraintViolationsException) cause;
        ret = new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST, cause, e.getViolations().iterator().next().getMessage());
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Constraint violation <" + e.getViolations().iterator().next().getMessage() + "> at resource <" + resource + ">");
    } else if (cause instanceof BusinessRuleException) {
        ret = new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST, cause, cause.getMessage());
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Business rule exception: <" + cause.getMessage() + "> at resource <" + resource + ">");
    } else {
        Status status = super.getStatus(throwable, resource);
        ret = new Status(status, throwable.getMessage());
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected server exception <" + ret.toString() + "> for throwable of type <" + throwable + "> at resource <" + resource + ">");
    }
    return ret;
}

@Override
public Representation getRepresentation(Status status, Request request, Response response) {
    String ret = "";
    if (status.getDescription() != null) {
        ret = status.getDescription();
    } else {
        ret = "unknown error";
    }
    return new StringRepresentation(ret, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
}
```

You can return a representation of the error in getRepresentation in whatever format (XML, JSON, HTML) you want.

Comment: Ok, but how do I send my own description message ? I see every where that StatusService should be overridden. This is what I have tried w/o any luck. I have over ridden the getStatus method of the custom status service, set the status and returned it. I have tried various things but the status on the client side always show as Server Internal Error and no error message / description is available.

Comment: I had to correct myself. You can send a representation of the error too via the StatusService by overriding getRepresentation. see my example above.

Comment: this constructor e.g. public Status(Status status, String description)  lets you pass the description.